# Windows 7 x64 vs Ubuntu 16

Tags: windows-7-x64, ubuntu-16.04

I've a Acer Aspire 5600U machine, which had windows 10 earlier. I installed Ubuntu 16 on this machine erasing all previous Operating Systems. Now, it says that there is no bootable disk and stuck at the boot screen.

So, i tried to go back to windows 7, and created a bootable Windows 7 x64 USB but the computer does not recognize the bootable USB either, whereas it does recognize bootable Ubutnu 16 OS USB.

I'm pretty sure there must be something i'm missing in the BIOS, but i've no clue what it is. I dont understand the whole concept of UEFI vs BIOS either.

So, if anyone has any ideas to resolve this, would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is struggling with this, here is the problem, how it was got solved.

I had to use Rufus tool to create GBT Partition with FAT32 file system. Looks like the drive i used earlier was in NTFS.

formatting it to FAT32 resolved the issue.